# Creating task in feed

Tags: chatter, tasks, activities

From [salesforce help](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=tasks_creating_a_task_in_a_feed.htm) we can create task in feed.But I don't see an option to create it.Can someone help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check Chatter is enabled, and then that Global Publisher Actions are enabled - I think they are what the help post is referring to